# Post API doesn't give any react

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, jhipster

I am developing an application with using JHipster(Java,Spring Boot,Angular).
I have course and student entities. Students should register courses with clicking register button after they logged in.
I wrote post api and tested it from swagger. IT WORKS FINE.
But when i try to link it to a button with angular1; it gives any react.

My Post API(I test it from swagger it works fine)

```
@PostMapping("/registercourse/{studentId}/{courseId}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Void> registerCourse(@PathVariable Long studentId,@PathVariable Long courseId) {
    log.debug("REST request to register {} Course : {} Student : {}", courseId,studentId);
    courseRepository.registerCourse(studentId,courseId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, courseId.toString())).build();
}
```

course.register.states.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
    .module('mucsApp')
    .config(stateConfig);

stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('course.register', {
            parent: 'entity',
            url: '/registercourse/:studentid/:courseid',
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
            },
            controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
                $scope.studentid = $stateParams.studentid;
                $scope.courseid = $stateParams.courseid;
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/' + $scope.studentid + '/' + $scope.courseid,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log("GREAT");
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                });
            }
        });
}})();
```

course.register.service.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('mucsApp')
        .factory('CourseRegister', CourseRegister);

CourseRegister.$inject = ['$resource'];

function CourseRegister ($resource) {
    var resourceUrl =  'api/registercourse/:studentid/:courseid';

    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
        'query': { method: 'POST', isArray: true},
        'save': {
            method: 'POST',
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var copy = angular.copy(data);
                return angular.toJson(copy);
            }
        }
    });
}})();
```

My html button:

```
<button type="submit"
        ui-sref="course.register({studentid:vm.mystudentid , courseid:course.id})"
        class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
    <span class="hidden-sm-down">Kaydol</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Is var resourceUrl =  'api/registercourse/:studentid/:courseid' correct?  What is the full URL if you tried going to the endpoint directly using SoapUI or Postman?

Answer (score 1):

Your Spring controller is looking for this:

```
@PostMapping("/registercourse/{studentId}/{courseId}")
```

Your `$http` call is posting to this:

```
url: 'http://localhost:8080/' + $scope.studentid + '/' + $scope.courseid
```

You need to change your call to:

```
url: 'http://localhost:8080/registercourse' + $scope.studentid + '/' + $scope.courseid
```

Also, your Controller is not actually using your `CourseRegister`. you need to inject that in your AngularJS controller if you want to use it.: `controller: function($scope, $stateParams,CourseRegister)`.

My two cents is that in your case, you are better of just using `$http`. I would put the [updated] `$http` call into your CourseRegister service, and use that. `$resource` would require more modifications than I think is worth it.

More on $resource is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: As it's a JHipster app, url should  start by /api but original poster did not show the RequestMapping on controller class. Also the angular 
 app is served from same origin as API, so url should not include localhost and port otherwise it will not work with gulp, it should start with '/api/registercourse'

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I changed my url and seperated controller and it workes fine! Thank you!

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I had left URLs as they were.  I test my FE/BE at different ports, so I tend to have this sort of thing during development.

Comment: @can , did this help at all, based on Gael's comments? Not sure if I should delete.